# Vue Custom Component with V-model

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component

I have a form which is built using custom components which is available for us to use.
NOTE: I do not have access to the custom components , adding @input solution will not work for me.
Is there any way i can get value from my custom components without making change in the component?

```
  <section class="container__content">
   <div>Details</div>
      <div class="personal-info">
        <textfield type="text" label="Name" placeholder="Shweta"></textfield>
         <textfield type="text" label="ID" placeholder="sm1234"></textfield>
       </div>
```

Comment: `any way i can get value from my custom components without making change in the component?` :-)

Comment: can you please share some code in which context you are trying to retrieve the values? (SO works this way, you show code people help you)

Comment: @volna Please Check.

Comment: Does this answer helps you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11563638/how-do-i-get-the-value-of-text-input-field-using-javascript ?

Comment: @volna no javascript can be used only typescript.

Comment: all typescript is just a version of JavaScript. Any valid JavaScript is valid typescript 

Comment: Typescript just adds restriction to the way you write JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

If i understand you properly you need the $refs object.
[https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-edge-cases.html#Accessing-Child-Component-Instances-amp-Child-Elements][1]
[1]: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-edge-cases.html#Accessing-Child-Component-Instances-amp-Child-Elements

basic code example:

```
<template>
<child ref="childA"></child>
<child ref="otherCHild></child>
</template>

this.$refs.childA.something
this.$refs.otherCHild.something
```

the two $refs variables will be the the value that is contained in the something variable in their respective children.

I use this in the utils libraries to keep an eye on changes that i want to trigger actions in the parent (like watching for upload completions or errors)